# How to implement eCharts inverse functionality, while keeping the y Axis title at the top?

Tags: echarts

I have implemented the [inverse function on echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.inverse) for charts, [however the chart title also switches from left to right](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.nameTextStyle.align). I am essentially looking for a way to keep the chart title at the top of my chart, regardless of whether inverse is set to true or false.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to define nameLocation as such:
`nameLocation: inverse ? 'start' : 'end',`

Which ensured it would stay placed at the top of the chart